# Collect several API call results

Tags: javascript, beginner, jquery, json

Want to brush up my rusty web dev skills. I want to call the twitch API for several channels and eventually call a callback function when all results are in without using a sync call.

I didn't work with JavaScript for a long time, so I'm not sure if my solution is a good way, especially how I figure out if the callback function should be called.

```
var Twitch = function() {
    var baseUrl = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/';
    var channels = ["freecodecamp", "storbeck", "terakilobyte", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "thomasballinger", "noobs2ninjas", "beohoff"];

    this.update = function(callback) {
        var result = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < channels.length; i++) {
            var qUrl = baseUrl + channels[i];
            var name = channels[i];
            $.getJSON(qUrl, success(name, result, callback));
        }
    }

    function success(name, result, callback) {
        return function(data) {
            result[name] = data;
            if (results.length == channels.length) {
                callback(result);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I can't elaborate a really good answer, you can take a look at [$.when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) to think in an alternative way of do the same job

Comment: Didn't saw this, looks nice. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this code is used like:

```
var twitch = new Twitch();
twitch.update(function(){
  // called each time a site responds
});
```

A few things:

First, I see little benefit of this functionality being written using a constructor. It appears to be a singleton by functionality as it makes no sense spawning multiple instances. Consider a singleton instead:

```
var Twitch = (function(){

  // stuff

  return {
    update: function(){...}
  };

}());
```

Next is your AJAX. As pointed in the comments, use `$.when` to listen to multiple jqXHR objects and call the callback once everyone is resolved. The native counterpart to `$.when` is `Promise.all`.

Next is to make `update` return a promise instead of handing it a callback. This way, your caller is allowed to listen not only for the success but also the failures.

Next is to take advantage of array methods like `map` instead of loops.

Your code could be simplified into:

```
var Twitch = (function(){

  var baseUrl = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/';
  var channels = ["freecodecamp", "storbeck", "terakilobyte", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "thomasballinger", "noobs2ninjas", "beohoff"];

  return {
    update: function(){
      var promises = channels.map(function(channel){
        return $.getJSON(baseUrl + channel).then(function(data){
          var result = {};
          result[channel] = data;
          return result;
        });
      });

      return $.when.apply(null, promises).then(function(){
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        return args.reduce(function(results, result){
          return $.extend(results, result);
        }, {});
      });
    }
  };

}());

// Usage
Twitch.update().then(function(results){
  // Succeeded
}, function(){
  // Failed
});
```

Now if you have ES6 available (via transpiler, or a modern browser), this can be simplified further by using the new syntax and making it more compact.

```
var Twitch = (function(){

  var baseUrl = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/';
  var channels = ["freecodecamp", "storbeck", "terakilobyte", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "thomasballinger", "noobs2ninjas", "beohoff"];

  return {
    update(){
      var promises = channels.map(channel => {
        return $.getJSON(`${baseUrl}${channel}`)
                .then(data => ({[channel]: data}));
      });

      return Promise.all(promises)
                    .then((...args) => args.reduce((results, result) => Object.assign(results, result), {}));
    }
  };

}());

// Usage
Twitch.update().then(function(results){
  // Succeeded
}, function(){
  // Failed
});
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me good hints where to look next. Can't remember promises where s thing when I worked with JS last time